# POSTGRESQL - ERROR: could not load library pgafis.so : undefined symbol: lfsparms_V2

Tags: postgresql, user-defined-functions, postgresql-9.4

I'm using PGAFIS library for fingerprint matching. For this i have installed postgresql and having some user defined c functions.

PGAFIS contain makefile, .control file, sql and unpacked sql file everything

I have compiled and pgafis.so file for the same and everyfile is on right location.

In my PGAdmin-III when i run  `CREATE EXTENSION pgafis` it gives me following error:

```
ERROR: could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/lib/pgafis.so": /usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/lib/pgafis.so: undefined symbol: lfsparms_V2
SQL state: XX000
```

Please help. Thanks in advance

(This is a follow-up from [Postgresql user defined c function issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44491217/398670))

Comment: The symbol in question comes from the [NBIS package](https://github.com/lessandro/nbis/blob/3d3b05f0144b706bed56407957bc00779baf2fa5/mindtct/src/lib/mindtct/globals.c#L161). Judging by the PGAFIS Makefile, it expected to find this definition in `/opt/nbis-5.0.0/lib/libmindtct.a`. Does this file exist?

Comment: /opt contain no nbis folder.. please guide how to proceed further..

Answer (score 0):

I expect you forgot to link to the required library.

Try adding

```
PG_LIBS = -lmindtct
```

or whatever. If it's not on the default linker path you'll need to need to add `-L/path/to/the/containing/directory` to `PG_CPPFLAGS` too.